# dependency injection between app and library in clojure

Tags: clojure, dependency-injection

I am splitting part of my app into a library

The library functionality has certain dependencies which must be injected by the app. I have modeled this with a protocol

```
(defprotocol MyLibDependencies
  (some-injected-capability [x]))

(defrecord Foo [y])
(defrecord Bar [y])

(defmulti render-response class)

(defmethod render-response Foo [val] {:ok (some-injected-capability (:y val))})
(defmethod render-response Bar [val] {:err (some-injected-capability (:y val))})
```

and here in the application I can provide an implementation:

```
(extend-type Object
  MyLibDependencies
  (some-injected-capability [x] (inc x)))

(comment
  (render-response (Foo. 10))   ;; => {:ok 11}
  (render-response (Bar. 10))   ;; => {:err 11}
  )
```

This works, however it feels like an abuse of protocols, because I need neither polymorphic dispatch, nor does the injected function necessarily require an argument (the protocol requires at least one argument to dispatch against it's class). What are my options?

Note that the records Foo and Bar are library domain types, and the `render-response` method is also library domain. I don't necessarily care how I define them, but the abstractions they represent are library domain.

Comment: Instead of injection, make all calls in the server be calls to protocol methods, and let the client provide a type that implements the protocol.

Comment: i dont understand how that is different from what i have, can you post code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit closer to how you would typically see protocols used to provide functionality from client code to a library:

```
;; lib.clj
(defprotocol MyLibDependencies
  (provide-status [this x])
  (provide-response [this x]))

(defn render-response
  [responder val]
  {:status (provide-status responder val)
   :code (provide-response responder val)})

;; client.clj
(defrecord Foo [y]
  MyLibDependencies
  (provide-status [this val]
    (if (even? val)
      :ok
      :err))
  (provide-response [this val]
    (+ y val)))

(defrecord Bar [y]
  MyLibDependencies
  (provide-status [this val]
    (if (odd? val)
      :ok
      :err))
  (provide-response [this val]
    (+ y val)))


(comment
  (render-response (Bar. 10) 1) ;; => {:status :ok :code 11}
  (render-response (Foo. 10) 1) ;; => {:status :err :code 11}
  )
```

There are numerous examples of this style of Clojure code in the wild - in fact most of the core functions that make up Clojure itself are end up resolving to calls to protocol methods provided by the specific datastructure being used, or multimethod calls extended for the individual datatypes.

Comment: Can it be done while keeping the records and method defined in the library?

Comment: You could use extend-type to add the protocol implementation to the record from the client, but I don't really see much benefit to defining the record in the lib. The pattern of adapting to use a type passed in from the client is the same as the kind of design done in order to use arguments passed in explicitly rather than global state. Remember that you can associate any key you like onto any record regardless of type, including a namespaced key that is specific to your lib.